# One Autosys job in multiple boxes

Tags: jobs, autosys

How to assign more than one box to a job?

Boxes: B1, B2

Jobs: V, W, X, Y, Z

B1 has V, W, and Y running in same sequence.

B2 has W, X and Z running in same sequence.

So, how to put W in B1 and B2 both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a single job to multiple box is **NOT** allowed,

*Alternative*,
Create two jobs of W such as `JOB_W_1` and `JOB_W_2` with different names but with the same command and place them in separate boxes

Incase you don't want both the job to run simultaneously, use the condition for `JOB_W_1` as `notrunning (JOB_W_2)` or `done (JOB_W_2)`

Job Tree would look like

```
├── BOX_1
│   ├── JOB_V
│   ├── JOB_W_1
│   └── JOB_X
└── BOX_2
    ├── JOB_W_2
    ├── JOB_Y
    └── JOB_Z
```

Downstream for any dependency use Success of:

- both jobs JOB_W_1 and JOB_W_2 or
- both boxes BOX_1 and BOX_2